# Which email servers currently send DMARC aggregate reports - and which do not yet?

Tags: email, dmarc

I've implemented a DMARC policy for my company's outgoing email. But I'm receiving surprisingly few aggregate reports back. So far only three domains: `gmail.com; yahoo.com; emailsrvr.com`

Does anyone who receives lots of reports or otherwise know which (big) servers send DMARC aggregate reports and which important ones do not at this point in time? Unfortunately, I don't know how otherwise to find out which servers do and don't send reports.

Maybe there's a website or directory that lists this, that'd be fantastic of course - I'm sure something like that should exist. But I could't find it after lots of research.

All I could find was this 4 year old post which only says who uses DMARC to filter, but not who sends reports: https://dmarc.org/2016/02/how-can-i-tell-who-is-using-dmarc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://us.dmarcian.com/dmarc-data-providers/) you can find a useful site on DMARC data providers, sorted on size.

The one big ESP missing from the list is Microsoft. Hotmail / Outlook.com used to send aggregate reports, but has stopped ever since the back end got migrated to Office 365.
[Here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365/why-doesn-t-o365-produce-dmarc-reporting/m-p/319757) you can find a good thread on how ridiculous this actually is...

Comment: Spot on as usual, thanks Reinto! This is amazing, also shows exactly how long it takes for DMARC reports to arrive. Love it. What does "Provider" mean here? The entity sending DMARC reports, so the domain that emails were sent *to*? I'm surprised Yahoo is first, not Gmail. Why would that be? Because Gmail doesn't send reports for email sent *from* Gmail/Gsuite - and that's 80% of all emails? It's a great dataset, shows you how many DMARC-report enabled emails are sent to various servers - so you can gauge relative incoming email amounts.

Comment: Yahoo! Mail bought Rocket Mail in 1997 and is about 7 years older than Gmail (2004). AOL, like Yahoo! is now a part of Verizon. And Yahoo! is sending reports for both, I believe. See here a list of popular webmail providers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_webmail_providers